# PHP (MySQL) Script doesn't read anything else once I add 'echo' and take something from table

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have a problem,

When I tried to list all users, to get their username/and others script didn't continue to read anything, it has stopped just after my echo input.

So when I put echo to get user's info it reads that input but it doesn't read anything after. See bellow there is a echo called 'userEmail' and it reads it with no problems but it doesn't go after signature. Now I have checked any everything works when i put it on a plain page but for some reason it stop readsing here.  I'm a newbie in this PHP so yeah. :)

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT userEmail FROM users");

while($userRow= mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Widget: user widget style 1 -->
            <div class="box box-widget widget-user">
                <div class="widget-user-header bg-blue" style="background-color:  center center;">
                </div>
                <div class="widget-user-image">
                    <img alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" src="//">
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 border-right">
                            <div class="description-block">
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.description-block -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->

                        <div class="col-sm-4 border-right">
                            <div class="description-block">
                                <h5 class="description-header">'.$userRow['userEmail'];'</h5>
                                <h5 class="description-text">'.$userRow['userSignature'];'</h5>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.description-block -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="description-block"></div>
                        <!-- /.description-block -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.widget-user -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of your script - shows errors and stuff - might be a fatal error somewhere :)

Comment: also mysql_* functions are deprecated and removed in php7 - switch to mysqli_*

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Your last closing div is closing nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You're ending your `echo` with a `;`. You need to concatenate the string with a `.` instead:

```
<h5 class="description-header">'.$userRow['userEmail'];'</h5>
<h5 class="description-text">'.$userRow['userSignature'];'</h5>
```

This should be:

```
<h5 class="description-header">'.$userRow['userEmail'].'</h5>
<h5 class="description-text">'.$userRow['userSignature'].'</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

in 
'.$userRow['
quates are conflict with together
change ' and " with together in all lines of your script
and then :

> ".$userRow['userEmail']."<

be sure will be ok